# The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context while upgrading project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I made the mistake and run the upgrade package command at package manager console.
Now i get a couple of errors.

The ./Views/Web.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>


    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The web.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
            <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true"/>
            <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true"/>
        <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true"/><section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true"/></sectionGroup></configSections>

  <connectionStrings>

  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>

    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>


    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>

  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers></system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true"/>
        <settings>
            <!-- This setting causes .NET to check certificate revocation lists (CRL) 
                 before trusting HTTPS certificates.  But this setting tends to not 
                 be allowed in shared hosting environments. -->
            <!--<servicePointManager checkCertificateRevocationList="true"/>-->
        </settings>
    </system.net><dotNetOpenAuth>
        <messaging>
            <untrustedWebRequest>
                <whitelistHosts>
                    <!-- Uncomment to enable communication with localhost (should generally not activate in production!) -->
                    <!--<add name="localhost" />-->
                </whitelistHosts>
            </untrustedWebRequest>
        </messaging>
        <!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
        <reporting enabled="true"/>
    <!-- This is an optional configuration section where aspects of dotnetopenauth can be customized. --><!-- For a complete set of configuration options see http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/configuration-options/ --><openid>
        <relyingParty>
                <security requireSsl="false">
                    <!-- Uncomment the trustedProviders tag if your relying party should only accept positive assertions from a closed set of OpenID Providers. -->
                    <!--<trustedProviders rejectAssertionsFromUntrustedProviders="true">
                        <add endpoint="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud" />
                    </trustedProviders>-->
                </security>
                <behaviors>
                    <!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
                         with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
                    <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty"/>
                </behaviors>
            </relyingParty></openid></dotNetOpenAuth><uri>
        <!-- The uri section is necessary to turn on .NET 3.5 support for IDN (international domain names),
             which is necessary for OpenID urls with unicode characters in the domain/host name.
             It is also required to put the Uri class into RFC 3986 escaping mode, which OpenID and OAuth require. -->
        <idn enabled="All"/>
        <iriParsing enabled="true"/>
    </uri></configuration>
```

and the packages.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.11.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.14.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="knockoutjs" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

How am i supposed to fix that?
Thank you

Comment: It looks like the `<bindingRedirect..` you have in the `<!-- This prevents the Windows Event Log ...` section of `web.config` is the issue - its specifies `newVersion="3.0.0.0"` but you want `newVersion="5.2.3.0"` (you set it previously but I assume the second instance overwrites it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke it is wrapped as comment

Comment: OK, but please remove commented code. When you don't format it correctly and have to scroll both ways its near impossible to tell

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling the package,

> update-package -reinstall

this always work in me when i had package error,
see this for documentation.
https://docs.nuget.org/consume/reinstalling-packages